# Why my css is loading from the base theme instead of custom theme on migrating the site?

Tags: css, magento, migration

I developed a site in magento on windows 7, and now my system has been updated and install an ubuntu 12.04 in it.

Now when I am running my site in browser I got an issue that my css is not loaded from the path which is loaded before.

Firstly my css path is like this

`http://127.0.0.1/magento/skin/frontend/default/sportation/css/style.css`

sportation is my custom theme, and now in ubuntu path is like this

`http://127.0.0.1/magento/skin/frontend/base/default/css/style.css`

Can anyone tell me why it is loading a css from the base theme I didn't understand, not only `style.css` every css is getting the path of the base theme.

My custom theme is still in working but not the css. How can I set the correct path.

Thanks.

Comment: have you clear cache ? and your template file is calling your theme file or base file?

Comment: yeah my cache is already disable from the starting.

Comment: and your template file is calling your theme file or base file?

Comment: yes it is calling my theme thats why i didn't understand what is the problem here.

Comment: have you check as per comment @Slimshadddyyy ?

Comment: In my Desingn tab, the only thing I do is to set the Default value to my custom design, and it work perfectly in the windows 7 nothing else to do in there. But I tried your solution in the ubuntu I set all the values to my custom theme but nothing happens. It still loads the css from the base theme.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment yet, Did you move the database along with this,  or is this a clean database on the new server? If so did you verify under system->configuration->design tab and verify that the themes config options are set to use your theme. Making sure package is set to "default"  and "sportation" is set for all of the theme settings including css.   In a move such as this you should delete the var/cache directory from FTP. regardless

Comment: Thanks for the reply Rob but I already did all these things but nothing happen. I moved the database with the site,I really didn't understand what is the reason behind this.

Comment: I change the xampp version also, on windows 7 my xampp version is 1.7.3 and in ubuntu my xampp version is 1.8.3-2. Is this causing any problem or what, I don't think so but mentioning all the things.